# Nom Parser To Unescape String

Tags: parsing, rust

I'm writing a [Nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom) parser for [RCS](https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/manual/html_node/File-format.html#File-format). RCS Files tend to be ISO-8859-1 encoded. One of the grammar productions is for a String. This is `@`-delimited and literal `@` symbols are escaped as `@@`.

```
@A String@ -> A String
@A @@ String@ -> A @ String
```

I have a working function (see end). `IResult` is from Nom, you either return the parsed thing, plus the rest of the unparsed input, or an `Error`/`Incomplete`. `Cow` is used to return a reference built on the original input slice if no unescaping was required, or an owned string if it was.

Are there any built in Nom macros that could have helped with this parse?

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;
use std::str;
use std::borrow::Cow;
use nom::*;

/// Parse an RCS String
fn string<'a>(input: &'a[u8]) -> IResult<&'a[u8], Cow<'a, str>> {
    let len = input.len();
    if len < 1 {
        return IResult::Incomplete(Needed::Unknown);
    }
    if input[0] != b'@' {
        return IResult::Error(Err::Code(ErrorKind::Custom(0)));
    }
    // start of current chunk. Chunk is a piece of unescaped input
    let mut start = 1;
    // current char index in input
    let mut i = start;
    // FIXME only need to allocate if input turned out to need unescaping
    let mut s: String = String::new();
    // Was the input escaped?
    let mut escaped = false;
    while i < len {
        // Check for end delimiter
        if input[i] == b'@' {
            // if there's another @ then it is an escape sequence
            if i + 1 < len && input[i + 1] == b'@' {
                // escaped @
                i += 1; // want to include the first @ in the output
                s.push_str(str::from_utf8(&input[start .. i]).unwrap());
                start = i + 1;
                escaped = true;
            } else {
                // end of string
                let result = if escaped {
                    s.push_str(str::from_utf8(&input[start .. i]).unwrap());
                    Cow::Owned(s)
                } else {
                    Cow::Borrowed(str::from_utf8(&input[1 .. i]).unwrap())
                };
                return IResult::Done(&input[i + 1 ..], result);
            }
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    IResult::Incomplete(Needed::Unknown)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the way to use the nom library is using the macro combinators. A quick browse of the [source code](https://github.com/Geal/nom) gives some [nice](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/master/tests/json.rs) [examples](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/master/tests/ini.rs) of parsers, including parsing of strings with escape characters. This is what I came up with:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

use nom::*;

named!(string< Vec<u8> >, delimited!(
    tag!("@"),
    fold_many0!(
        alt!(
            is_not!(b"@") |
            map!(
                complete!(tag!("@@")),
                |_| &b"@"[..]
            )
        ),
        Vec::new(),
        |mut acc: Vec<u8>, bytes: &[u8]| {
            acc.extend(bytes);
            acc
        }
    ),
    tag!("@")
));

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    assert_eq!(string(b"@string@"), IResult::Done(&b""[..], b"string".to_vec()));
    assert_eq!(string(b"@string with @@ escapes@"), IResult::Done(&b""[..], b"string with @ escapes".to_vec()));
    assert_eq!(string(b"@invalid string"), IResult::Incomplete(Needed::Size(16)));
}
```

As you can see, I simply copy the bytes into a vector using `Vec::extend` - you could be more sophisticated here and return a `Cow` byte slice if you wanted.

The `escaped!` macro does not appear to be of use in this case unfortunately, as it can't seem to work when the terminator is the same as the escape character (which is actually a pretty common case).